# Cut out part of the data shown in serial monitor of Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm new member here and also a joiner in programming
i try to extract information from my vehicle using OBD-II cable adapter. I try simple code to read the RPM and successfully got it and print it in serial monitor but i face a simple problem. Serial monitor display the PID-Code + current value of RPM as shown below:

010C849      where 010C: refer to RPM-PID used     and 849: current value of RPM

so can i cutout the HEX number from the result and just display the value of RPM such as (849)

i used the following code:

[Here is an example of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG3xZ.png) `

```
#include <OBD2UART.h>
COBD obd;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  obd.begin();
  while (!obd.init());
}
void loop()
{
  int value;
  if (obd.readPID(PID_RPM, value)) {
        Serial.println(value);
        delay(1000);
  }
}
```

`

Comment: `Serial.println()` cannot print half an integer in hex and the other half in decimal.  I think COBD may also be sending bytes out.  You should add an extra line feed, as `Serial.println()`, before your rpm value to verify this, then investigate the CODB source code for the extra printout if necessary.

Comment: Conversely, the eventual application that uses the data can use the ID `010C`to verify that the nubers following it are indeed the RPM reading.  This may prove beneficial if you plan to extract different sensor readings from your engine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually the reason behind this i want to go through driving behavior analysis and the first thing that i should made is to check the RPM during the trip and next step is to collect speed data by changing the PID_RPM to PID_SPEED and calculate the differences between two consecutive readings

Comment: Then, you should keep the ID as is, and change your software or excel script to make use of it.  You'll be able to collect both speed and RPM simultaneously and have a quite useable data set.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex, to cut out a pattern, but Arduino (and, in general, C++) does not provide support for regular expression parsing.

Once you have the string, you can use `indexOf()` and `substring()` to extract substrings. Once you have a substring, you can use `toCharArray()` to extract the character array, and atoi() to convert that to an integer.

Once you have integer values you can print them out.